# aws auto-stop-idle does not detect papermill

Tags: linux, amazon-web-services, amazon-sagemaker, papermill

I am using papermill to parametrize jupyter notebook deployed on AWS Sagemaker. I also used this [lifestyle configuration](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples/tree/master/scripts/auto-stop-idle) that will auto shutdown if there are no running/idle notebooks. Unfortunately, it does not detect the Papermill process and continues to shutdown after reaching the specified idle time. What do I need to do to keep Sagemaker alive until the completion of Papermill

Answer (score 1):

You could edit the [idleness detection script](https://github.com/aws-samples/amazon-sagemaker-notebook-instance-lifecycle-config-samples/blob/master/scripts/auto-stop-idle/autostop.py) to account for papermill processes.

Alternatively, if you have async jobs, which you can formulate as python code, you could use [SageMaker processing jobs](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/sagemaker/latest/dg/processing-job.html) to execute them, which will not depend on your notebook instance being up.